# Issue in setting delimiter in combo ext js 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am setting slash(/) as the delimiter in a ext js xtype combo. On tab out, the delimiter is again changed to a comma(,). This only happens when I select values from the list. When I paste the values, the delimiter stays a slash.

I am using a combo in the ext js grid.

Any specific reason for this behavior ?

```
Ext.define('PromoMassCopy.view.masscopy.MassCopyGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  xtype: 'array-grid',
  alias: 'widget.massCopyGrid',
  store: 'MassCopyStore',
  id: 'massCopyGrid',
  width: 500,
  height: 350,
  multiSelect: true,
  autoScroll: true,
  stateful: true,
  stateId: 'stateGrid',
  headerBorders: false,

  viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection: true
  },

  columns: [
  {
    header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.SourceOffer"],
    width: 300,
    dataIndex: 'SOURCEOFFER',
    id: 'SOURCEOFFER'
  }, {
    header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.AdWeek"],
    width: 95,
    dataIndex: 'ADWEEK',
    id: 'ADWEEK'
  }, {
    header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.Vehicle"],
    width: 300,
    dataIndex: 'VEHICLE',
    id: 'VEHICLE'
  }, {
    header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.DestinationOffer"],
    dataIndex: 'DESTINATIONOFFER',
    flex: 1,
    sortable: false,
    editor:
    {
      xtype : 'combo',
      id:'DESTINATIONOFFERCOMBO',
      typeAhead: true,
      triggerAction: 'all',
      allowBlank: true,
      selectOnTab: true,
      displayField: 'promotion',
      valueField: 'promotionID',
      queryMode: 'local',
      autoRenderer:true,
      forceSelection:false,
      store: 'DestinationOfferStore',
      scope: this,
      multiSelect: true,
      delimiter: '/'
    },
    filter:
    {
      type: 'string',
    }

  }
  ],
  selModel : {
    selType : 'checkboxmodel',
    ignoreRightMouseSelection: true,
    checkOnly: true // IMP: Getting cell model issue if flag set to true
  },
  plugins: [
  {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1
  },{
      ptype: 'rowexpander',
      rowBodyTpl : [
        '<div class="subGrid"></div>'
      ],
      selectRowOnExpand: false,
      expandOnEnter : false,
      expandOnDblClick : false
  }
  ],

  bbar: [{xtype:'paging'}]
    edit: function(editor, context, eOpts) {

        var errorMsg = Ext.getCmp('promoStatusMessage').html;
        if(errorMsg != null && errorMsg.indexOf("Some offers") != -1) {
            return;
        }

        var gridRow = Ext.getCmp('massCopyGrid').store.getAt(context.rowIdx);
        var sourceOffer = gridRow.data['SOURCEOFFER'];
        var destinationOffers = gridRow.data['DESTINATIONOFFER'];
        destinationOffers = destinationOffers != null ? destinationOffers.toString() : null;
        PromoMassCopy.app.getController('MassCopyController').updateDestinationOffer(sourceOffer, destinationOffers);

        // Re-create the DMDUnit grid
        var subGridDiv = Ext.DomQuery.select('div.subGrid')[context.rowIdx];
        if( subGridDiv.children.length > 0 ) {
          return;
        }

        var dmdUnitStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
        {
            storeId:'DmdUnitStore' + i,
            fields:['demandUnits', 'description', 'retailPrice', 'effectivePrice'],
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url: URIMAP.get('LOADDMDUNITS')
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, records, success) {
                    var grid = Ext.getCmp('tGrid' + (i-1));
                    Ext.each(records, function(item, index) {
                        var row = grid.getView().getNode(index);
                        Ext.fly(row).highlight('#000000', {
                            attr: 'color',
                            duration:9000000
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        dmdUnitStore.proxy.extraParams = {
            promoOffer: sourceOffer
        };
        dmdUnitStore.load();

        var tgrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: 'DmdUnitStore' + i,
            id: 'tGrid' + i,
            stateful: true,
            stateId: 'dmdStateGrid',
            disableSelection: true,
            submitValue: false,
            xtype: 'array-grid',
            viewConfig: {
                enableTextSelection: false
            },
            loadMask: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            columns: [
            {
                header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.DmdUnits"],
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'demandUnits',
                hideable: false
            },
            {
                header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.Description"],
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'description',
                hideable: false
            },
            {
                header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.RetailPrice"],
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'retailPrice',
                hideable: false
            },
            {
                header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.EffectivePrice"],
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'effectivePrice',
                hideable: false
            }
          ],
          height: 100,
          renderTo: subGridDiv
        });
        i++;
        // Issue: Cannot read property 'isGroupHeader' of null
        tgrid.getEl().swallowEvent([
            'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click',
            'contextmenu', 'mouseover', 'mouseout',
            'dblclick', 'mousemove'
        ]);
    },
    select : function(selectionModel, record, index, eOpts) {
      PromoMassCopy.app.getController('MassCopyController').updatePromoSelection(record.data, true);
    },
    deselect : function(selectionModel, record, index, eOpts) {
      PromoMassCopy.app.getController('MassCopyController').updatePromoSelection(record.data, false);
    }
  },

  signTpl: '<span style="' +
  'color:{value:sign(\'"#cf4c35"\',\'"#73b51e"\')}"' +
  '>{text}</span>'
      this.callParent();
      var i = 0;
      this.view.on('expandbody', function(rowNode, record, body) {
        var subGridDiv = Ext.DomQuery.select('div.subGrid',body)[0];
        subGridDiv.innerText = '';
        if(subGridDiv.children.length > 0) {
          return;
        }

        var dmdUnitStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
        {
            storeId:'DmdUnitStore' + i,
            fields:['demandUnits', 'description', 'retailPrice', 'effectivePrice'],
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url: URIMAP.get('LOADDMDUNITS')
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, records, success) {
//                    Ext.getCmp('tGrid' + (i-1)).bindStore(store);
                    var grid = Ext.getCmp('tGrid' + (i-1));
                    Ext.each(records, function(item, index) {
                        var row = grid.getView().getNode(index);
                        Ext.fly(row).highlight('#000000', {
                            attr: 'color',
                            duration:9000000
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        dmdUnitStore.proxy.extraParams = {
         promoOffer: record.data["SOURCEOFFER"]
        };
        dmdUnitStore.load();

        var tgrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
          store: 'DmdUnitStore' + i,
          id: 'tGrid' + i,
          stateful: true,
          stateId: 'dmdStateGrid',
          disableSelection: true,
          submitValue: false,
          xtype: 'array-grid',
          viewConfig: {
            enableTextSelection: false
          },
          loadMask: true,
          multiSelect: false,
          columns: [
            {
              header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.DmdUnits"],
              flex: 1,
              dataIndex: 'demandUnits',
              hideable: false
            },
            {
              header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.Description"],
              flex: 1,
              dataIndex: 'description',
              hideable: false
            },
            {
              header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.RetailPrice"],
              flex: 1,
              dataIndex: 'retailPrice',
              hideable: false
            },
            {
              header: PROMOLABELS["PromoMassCopy.Label.EffectivePrice"],
              flex: 1,
              dataIndex: 'effectivePrice',
              hideable: false
            }
          ],
          height: 100,
          renderTo: subGridDiv
        });
        i++;
        // Issue: Cannot read property 'isGroupHeader' of null
        tgrid.getEl().swallowEvent([
            'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click',
            'contextmenu', 'mouseover', 'mouseout',
            'dblclick', 'mousemove'
        ]);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: added the code...

Comment: While debugging I noticed that when I select values from the list, and get the value in the blur method of combo, the values are returned as an Array. While, on pasting directly to the combo, the values are returned as string separated by the delimiter slash.

Comment: Hi @Ninad Singh Negi, I am facing exactly same issue. Have you got any solution for the same. Thank you